# ClassCastException using EclipseLink DescriptorCustomizer API in Liberty

Tags: websphere, eclipselink, websphere-liberty

We are using websphere-liberty:23.0.0.11-kernel-java17-openj9-ubi

with feature

```
<feature>persistence-3.0</feature>
```

and we want to use EclipseLink History https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

we add

```
@Customizer(HistoryCustomizer.class)
```

to our Entity class
but we get code exceptions all the time
The question is
which artifactId/version should we add to the pom.xml to support EclipseLink with Liberty with persistence 3.0?

I added such depedency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and my DescriptorCustomizer

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.history.HistoryPolicy;

public class HistoryCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addHistoryTableName("EMPLOYEE_HIST");
        policy.addStartFieldName("START_DATE");
        policy.addEndFieldName("END_DATE");
        descriptor.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

, but i got error message about ClassCastException

```
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.3.v202208190922): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [jpa-unit] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ibm.saas.siusermgr.application.scope.HistoryCustomizer cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer (com.ibm.saas.siusermgr.application.scope.HistoryCustomizer is in unnamed module of loader com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader @2bba175e; org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @3cab2487)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Configure access to Third Party APIs

As mentioned in the [doc](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/class-loader-library-config.html#3rd-party):

> By default, applications do not have access to the third-party APIs that are available in Open Liberty

So even though the `persistence-3.0` feature documents [providing APIs](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/persistence-3.0.html#_third_party_api_packages_provided_by_this_feature)  like `org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer`, (plus `HistoryPolicy` and the other EclipseLink classes), these will not be available to your application without one additional piece of server configuration.

### server.xml

Configure a `<classloader>` element for your application like:

```xml
<application id="testApp" name="testApp" type="war" location="testApp.war">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="+third-party" />
</application>
```

### Suggest 'provided'-scope dependency

There's probably less opportunity for confusion to use a `provided`-scope dependency to clearly load these classes from the runtime-provided version of the library rather than packaging it within your application. It's true that the default "parent-first" classloading might make this not really matter, at first.  Still, I'd suggest this as a better starting point, unless/until you really need to consider using your own version (beyond the scope of this post).  It's also a bit smaller footprint.

#### pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

### References

- https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/class-loader-library-config.html
- https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/classloader.html

Comment: Yes it works adding classloader apiTypeVisibility="+third-party" /> and change in pom from compile to provided